# EF Core 7.0 Migration Ignores DeleteBehavior.NoAction

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-7.0

I have an EF Core model with a root entity type that has multiple one-to-many relationships with other entity types. Some of these child types also relate to each other, so I understand that I need to take precautions to avoid circular reference issues when deleting a root entity instance.

Without any explicit model builder configuration between the root entity type and its child types, the resulting migration includes clauses like this:

```
migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_Merchants_Platforms_PlatformId",
    table: "Merchants",
    column: "PlatformId",
    principalTable: "Platforms",
    principalColumn: "Id");
```

If I attempt to run this migration, I see the following error:

[image]

In an attempt to solve this problem, I added explicit model builder configurations, which force `NoAction` on delete. Here's one example, applied to the child entity type:

```
builder
    .HasOne(e => e.Platform)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.PlatformId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

The above explicit change has no effect on the generated migration. However, if I change the `DeleteBehavior` to something other than `NoAction`, it produces the desired effect:

```
builder
    .HasOne(e => e.Platform)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.PlatformId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_Merchants_Platforms_PlatformId",
    table: "Merchants",
    column: "PlatformId",
    principalTable: "Platforms",
    principalColumn: "Id",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

Based on what I am seeing above, I guess `NoAction` is the default configuration and is implicitly applied when a migration is executed. However, if that's the case, it is not clear why I am seeing runtime migration errors.

Can anyone suggest the correct model builder configuration to force `NoAction` in the generated migration?